# lm: use product of two variables as a single variable

Tags: r, output, regression

I am running the following piece of code:

```
lm(ath ~ HAPP + IQ2 + OPEN2 + INCOME*EXPEC,data=data)
```

Which, of course, lead me to the output:

```
Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2644 -0.5461 -0.0223  0.4158  3.2217 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   5.730e+00  3.141e+00   1.824 0.068112 .  
HAPP         -7.765e-02  8.958e-02  -0.867 0.386014    
IQ2           5.080e-04  7.453e-05   6.816 9.38e-12 ***
OPEN2        -5.038e-06  5.114e-06  -0.985 0.324640    
INCOME       -1.837e-02  1.211e-01  -0.152 0.879395    
EXPEC        -3.336e-01  1.161e-01  -2.873 0.004067 ** 
INCOME:EXPEC  2.645e-03  7.597e-04   3.481 0.000499 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi)    9.489      1.363    6.96 3.41e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 222.5 on 8 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.6938
Number of iterations: 36 (BFGS) + 4 (Fisher scoring)
```

I need to drop the INCOME and EXPEC lines (with Estimate, Std. Error, z value and Pr(>|z|)) from the regression in a really elegant way (I need to run like a million models, so I can't do it by hand one by one). Please note **that those variables (INCOME and EXPEC) were not included in the original set of individual variables**. This is, ONLY the requested variables (and the demanded interactions, of course) should be printed.

Any piece of advice?

Thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AsIs` function. See the example below;

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + I(Petal.Length * Petal.Width) , data = iris)
fit

# Call:
#   lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + I(Petal.Length * Petal.Width), 
#      data = iris)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)                    Sepal.Width  
# 4.1072                         0.2688  
# I(Petal.Length * Petal.Width)  
# 0.1578  

library(broom)
tidy(fit)
# term  estimate   std.error statistic      p.value
# 1                   (Intercept) 4.1072163 0.266529393 15.409994 1.702125e-32
# 2                   Sepal.Width 0.2687704 0.081280587  3.306698 1.186597e-03
# 3 I(Petal.Length * Petal.Width) 0.1578160 0.007517941 20.991921 4.426899e-46
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need part of the coefficients you can just use the coef function from base R and subset the indices you like. For example:

```
a1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + I(Petal.Length * Petal.Width) , data = iris)
coefficients(a1)[1:2]

(Intercept) Sepal.Width 
  4.1072163   0.2687704
```

If you need the formula call as well you could do a1$call

```
a1$call
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + I(Petal.Length * Petal.Width), 
data = iris)
```

Or if you need any other argument just take a look at str(a1) or str(summary(a1))